# Jinja2 indentation when using inline and non-inline blocks

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the template below:

```html
{% macro entry(e) %}
<li>
    <a href="{% if 'link' in e %}{{ e.link }}{% else %}{{ e.path }}{% endif %}">
        <code>{{ e.title }}</code>
    </a>{% if e.desc  %} - {{ e.desc }}{% endif %}
    {% if e.date %}<time datetime="{{ e.date }}"> ({{ e.date.split('-')[0] }})</time>{% endif %}
</li>
{% endmacro %}
<ul>
    {% for e in entries %}
    {{ entry(e) }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

which I'm trying to render into this HTML with proper indentation and no blank lines:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="link">
            <code>title</code>
        </a> - desc
        <time datetime="2020"> (2020)</time>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried various permutations of `trim_blocks` and `lstrip_blocks` to no avail.  How can I achieve the desired output?

Sample code:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, Template

foo = (
    (True, True),
    (True, False),
    (False, True),
    (False, False),
)

template_string = """
{% macro entry(e) %}
<li>
    <a href="{% if 'link' in e %}{{ e.link }}{% endif %}">
        <code>{{ e.title }}</code>
    </a>{% if e.desc  %} - {{ e.desc }}{% endif %}
    {% if e.date %}<time datetime="{{ e.date }}"> ({{ e.date.split('-')[0] }})</time>{% endif %}
</li>
{% endmacro %}
<ul>
    {% for e in entries %}
    {{ entry(e) }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
"""

entries = [
    {'title': 'title', 'date': '2020', 'desc': 'desc', 'link': 'link'}
]

for trim_blocks, lstrip_blocks in foo:
    env = Environment(trim_blocks=trim_blocks, lstrip_blocks=lstrip_blocks)

    template = env.from_string(template_string)

    print("------------------------")
    print("trim_blocks:", trim_blocks)
    print("lstrip_blocks:", lstrip_blocks)
    print("------------------------")
    print(template.render(entries=entries))

# ------------------------
# trim_blocks: True
# lstrip_blocks: True
# ------------------------
# 
# <ul>
#     <li>
#     <a href="link">
#         <code>title</code>
#     </a> - desc<time datetime="2020"> (2020)</time></li>
# 
# </ul>
# ------------------------
# trim_blocks: True
# lstrip_blocks: False
# ------------------------
# 
# <ul>
#         <li>
#     <a href="link">
#         <code>title</code>
#     </a> - desc    <time datetime="2020"> (2020)</time></li>
# 
#     </ul>
# ------------------------
# trim_blocks: False
# lstrip_blocks: True
# ------------------------
# 
# 
# <ul>
# 
#     
# <li>
#     <a href="link">
#         <code>title</code>
#     </a> - desc
# <time datetime="2020"> (2020)</time>
# </li>
# 
# 
# </ul>
# ------------------------
# trim_blocks: False
# lstrip_blocks: False
# ------------------------
# 
# 
# <ul>
#     
#     
# <li>
#     <a href="link">
#         <code>title</code>
#     </a> - desc
#     <time datetime="2020"> (2020)</time>
# </li>
# 
#     
# </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want the combination of `trim_blocks` and `lstrip_blocks` both being `False`. So, the last version you have is actually quite close.

To achieve the desired output though, you will need to make use of [whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control) mechanisms provided by Jinja2. In particular, you will be interested in this:

> You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus
> sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment,
> or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block
> will be removed:

Therefore, by adding `-` signs in the `for` loop and `macro`, you can remove the unwanted newlines which occur upon expansion.

In the case of the `for` loop, add it to both sides of start and end of the block. However, in the case of the `macro`, add it only on one side -- if you add it to both, it will merge the `<ul>` and `<li>` onto the same line (and similarly for the closing tags).

The following should work for you:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, Template

template_string = """
{%- macro entry(e) %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% if 'link' in e %}{{ e.link }}{% endif %}">
            <code>{{ e.title }}</code>
        </a>{% if e.desc  %} - {{ e.desc }}{% endif %}
        {% if e.date %}<time datetime="{{ e.date }}"> ({{ e.date.split('-')[0] }})</time>{% endif %}
    </li>
{% endmacro -%}
<ul>
    {%- for e in entries -%}
        {{ entry(e) }}
    {%- endfor -%}
</ul>
"""

entries = [
    {'title': 'title', 'date': '2020', 'desc': 'desc', 'link': 'link'}
]

env = Environment(trim_blocks=False, lstrip_blocks=False)
template = env.from_string(template_string)
print(template.render(entries=entries))
```

Which gives the desired output:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="link">
            <code>title</code>
        </a> - desc
        <time datetime="2020"> (2020)</time>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Maybe I don't understand the complexity of the problem, but why doesn't the Jinja project simply make all its directives do this automatically?  Seems like a more sane default than what we have now.

Comment: And by "this", I mean if a directive is on a line surrounded only by whitespace, delete the line.

Comment: Fair question, its a design choice probably related to efficiency. HTML readability likely wasn't a priority. In reality though, HTML (and more commonly JS) is often minified before sending to the client.